# ¿Cómo crear un trigger que al eliminar una fila de una tabla, elimine una fila relacionada de otra tabla en mysql?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger

Tengo 2 tablas: Empleados y Vendedores

La tabla Empleados contiene los campos

- id_E
- Nombre
- Sueldo
- Grupo_trabajo

Y la tabla Vendedores, esta referenciada a Empleados, los empleados que pertenezcan al grupo_trabajo = 6, son vendedores, esta tabla contiene los campos:

- id_R
- Nombre
- Apellido
- Empleados_id_E (Llave foránea)

Para poder eliminar un elemento de la tabla Empleados, se necesita borrar primero el elemento relacionado de la tabla Vendedores por la cuestion de la llave foránea.

Retomando el tema de la pregunta, ¿cómo sería el trigger para que al borrar un elemento de la tabla Empleados, elimine la fila relacionada de Vendedores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estás usando MySQL, podrías probar con este código. Lo acabo de chequear y funciona correctamente

```
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_empleado` AFTER DELETE ON `vendedores`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE 
      FROM empleados
     WHERE empleados.id_e = old.id_e;
END
```

Lo que hace el código es "oir" los deletes de la tabla vendedores y para esas filas luego de haber sido eliminadas utilizar el id de empleado old.id_e para eliminarlo también de la tabla empleados.

Comment: Hola @Luciano. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por aportar! ¿Podrías comentar, aunque sea brevemente, por qué este código solucionaría el problema?

Answer (score 0):

cueque y ejecute el codigo y si funciona, lo modifque para poder eliminar de la tabla empleados pero fue de gran ayuda te lo agradezco. El codigo quedo de la siguiente manera, para si a alguien le fuese util.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ´delete_empleado´ 
BEFORE DELETE ON Empleados 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   IF (old.Grupo_trabajo = 6) THEN 
      DELETE FROM Vendedores WHERE Empleado_id_E = old.id_E; 
   END IF; 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
use apractica;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER ELIMINADO before DELETE ON datos_civiles

for each row

begin

    DELETE FROM datos_sensibles WHERE cedula=old.cedula;
end //

DELIMITER ;
```

Recuerda poner el `BEFORE` Y el `OLD`.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe brevemente cómo funciona esta consulta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.