# SQL Borrar tabla con foreign key

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

Buen día, estoy empezando con SQL y durante el desarrollo del proyecto surgió mi duda.

El tema es que tengo una tabla Detalle

Y una tabla Producto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema surge cuando quiero eliminar un producto, debido a la referencia que tiene por parte de DetalleV no puedo eliminarlo, sé que para eliminarlo necesitaría eliminar el detalleV que hace la referencia, pero, me gustaría saber si es posible eliminar un Producto sin borrar el detalleV que hace referencia a él.
He escuchado que con ALTER TABLE es posible eliminar la referencia de la tabla, pero yo solo necesito que la referencia se elimine del registro, de forma que el producto queda eliminado pero el DetalleV no.
Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Hola, Kenneth. De acuerdo a la teoría de las tablas relacionales, lo que quieres haría perder el sentido a la funcionalidad de las relaciones. Más que alterar las claves foráneas delas tablas, ¿no te vendría mejor simplemente agregar un campo booleano a la tabla padre `Producto`, llamado, por ejemplo "Eliminado"? De ese modo, no eliminas el registro, pero puedes usar dicho campo para filtrar tus consultas futuras, sin perder trazabilidad histórica. Es una alternativa.

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomiendo que al declarar las tablas utilices ON DELETE CASCADE, tal que así:

```
CREATE TABLE rooms (
    room_no INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    room_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    building_no INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (building_no)
        REFERENCES buildings (building_no)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

En tu caso tendrías que poner ON DELETE CASCADE en la declaración de tu tabla de detalle, así cuando elimines de la tabla principal, automáticamente se eliminará/n el/los registro/s asociado/s.

Te dejo un link donde se explica la teoría por si lo precisas:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

De esta forma no te dará el error de que necesitas borrarla antes. Sin embargo, si te interesa guardar esos registros, yo me crearía una tabla igual que detalle, pero con otro nombre, detalle_historico, de esta forma, antes de eliminar el registro asociado, copias los datos y los guardas en la tabla detalle_historico, así podrás eliminar de la tabla principal y conservar esos registros aunque no pertenezcan a la misma tabla de detalle. Esto lo puedes hacer automático con un trigger de la tabla detalle que se ejecute cada vez que vayas a eliminar un registro de la misma. Te dejo a continuación un ejemplo de trigger:

[¿Cómo crear un trigger que al eliminar una fila de una tabla, elimine una fila relacionada de otra tabla en mysql?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41622/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-trigger-que-al-eliminar-una-fila-de-una-tabla-elimine-una-fila-r)

En ese caso elimina de otra tabla, a ti te interesa que añada en otra el registro que vas a eliminar.

Lo que comentas acerca de realizar el alter table para quitar la restricción de la foreign key no te la recomiendo.. Tendrías que hacerlo cada vez que quieras borrar un registro y si vuelves luego a añadirle la restricción (no estoy segura si te dejará esto último tan libremente si ya tienes datos en las tablas) te va a quedar una BBDD inconsistente debido a que tendrá registros en detalle que no tendrá en la tabla padre y esto puede causar errores en un futuro..

Comment: Según entiendo el requerimiento de Kenneth es eliminar el registro padre, pero *sin* eliminar el registro hijo (lo cual no tiene sentido para mí, pero es lo que él solicita...).

Comment: ostras cierto, voy a editarla xD que la he leido mal, gracias, aunque cierto, tiene sentido 0

Comment: Hola, gracias por sus respuestas, ambas me ayudaron a solucinar el problema.
Agregué el campo Eliminado que me recomendó quinqui, me facilitó la manipulación de los empleados y me permite mantener los detalles y la eliminación on cascade (no la conocía, soy nuevo en SQL) para eliminar empleados cuyos detalles ya no son utiles.
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo siempre en las tablas troncales (Producto) manejar una variable 'Estado' (true o false), y así cuando querrás dar de baja solo le actualizas el 'Estado' a 'false'. 
Eso te evitara perder información de tu base de datos y es algo que se hace en cualquier lado para no perder informacion